# Two labels for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to get a date value to display below the name value on the table view but I keep getting error messages. "Cannot assign the value of type 'Date' to type string?"

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    let ots = OTSs[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = ots.branch!
    cell.textLabel?.text = ots.enterDate!



    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got several issues.

> "Cannot assign the value of type 'Date' to type string?"

That is the first. Exactly what the error says. `cell.textLabel?.text` expects a `String` object and you are giving it a `Date` object. You need to convert the `Date` to a `String`, which can be done with the [`DateFormatter` class](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter).

The second issue you have, is if you want two text labels, what you are doing is setting the text twice for the SAME label.

Instead of:

`cell.textLabel?.text = ots.branch!
 cell.textLabel?.text = ots.enterDate!`

you would need to set two different labels, either using a custom cell or one of the ones Apple has preconfigured to have a 2nd UILabel (I believe they call the second label `cell.detailTextLabel` or something along those lines).